# Site stuck to top-left corner in mobile (android)

Tags: android, html, css, mobile, centering

I've been painfully trying to center align a website in mobile (Andropid OS ICS 4.2.2) but it stays stuck to the top-left corner of the screen, slightly clipped.
I've tried jQuery and CSS only... same result. In desktop computers works fine.

This is what I have now - HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    ...
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#wrapper {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 1370px; height: 910px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -455px; /* half of #wrapper height */
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -685px; /* half of #wrapper width */
}
```

The online result: [link](http://www.novaplaquemar.pt/indexOK_pt.php)

[image]

By the way, the jQuery that I tried was this:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  $('#wrapper').css({
    left: ($(window).width() - $('#wrapper').outerWidth())/2,
    top: ($(window).height() - $('#wrapper').outerHeight())/2
    });
});

$(window).resize(); // To initially run the function
```

Any ideas?

**>>>>> Update 1 - @Moob suggestion <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<**

```
#wrapper {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1370px; height: 910px;
    top: 0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Still crops the top, but not the left side. Not centered.

[image]

Comment: do you have the code above inside `$(document).ready(function () { code });`?

Comment: It was in an external file in $(document).ready(), yes.

Comment: Doesn't a CSS size need a unit? That is, `px`?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>`<div id="wrapper">...` cannot be closed with `</wrapper>`. You must close the `</div>`</strike>

You could try to centre the element like this instead:

```
#wrapper {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1370px; height: 910px;
    top: 0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    margin:auto;
}
```

[Demo of centred div](http://jsfiddle.net/evn3j/)

... but I suspect that the mobile's resolution is less than the dimensions of your `#wrapper`

Comment: It's properly closed with a </div> - my mistake.

Comment: I've adopted your CSS and it has gotten slightly better. It's no longer clipped on the left side but remains at the top side and it's not centered. As to the mobile's resolution, there must be a way to adapt to the screen size. I'm going to add images of how it's looking.

Comment: Added mobile screenshot.